# Using Typescript api create an object in specific pattern from array of object, How can i retrive data using for loop in typescript?

Tags: mysql, node.js, arrays, json, typescript

Here I attached my typescript API using MySQL database, I have use `foreach` method for execute those two query because I need to get from those two query attached corresponding ID. So I need modification in the `foreach` loop, I will show my output which I need.

```js
let values = employerRes.reduce((prev: any, curr: any) => ({
  ...prev, [curr.issuer_id]: {
    issuer_id: curr.issuer_id,
    ...prev[curr.issuer_id], [(curr.name).replaceAll(' ', "_")]: curr[`${curr.datatype}_value`]
               
Object.values(values).forEach((x: any) => {
  Object.values(getEmployerDetail).forEach((Benefit: any) => {
    if (x.issuer_id == Benefit.issuer_id) {
      Object.assign(values[id],{getEmployerDetail} )
    }
  })
})
```

I am getting this output all is coming in single object.

```json
[
    {
        "issuer_id": 2639,
        "job_title": "Sales Manager",
        "hr-contact": "9767865459",
        "adress": "bangalore",
        "image": "http://localhost:3003/public/uploads/company-logos/undefined",
        "job_type": "top",
        "company_name": "Limendo",
        "cover_image": "http://localhost:3003/public/uploads/company-logos/undefined",
        "number_of_employees": null,
        "overview": "What is a company overview? A company overview provides the reader of your business plan with basic background information about your company so they have an understanding of what you do, who the management team is and what customers your business serves.",
        "getEmployerDetail": [
            {
                "issuer_id": 2639,
                "Field_of_activity": "Jobs",
                "id": 111,
                "Section": "Communes",
                "Content": "Mühlwald",
                "foa_section_content_id": 111
            },
            {
                "issuer_id": 2639,
                "Field_of_activity": "Jobs",
                "id": 112,
                "Section": "Communes",
                "Content": "Wolkenstein in Gröden",
                "foa_section_content_id": 112
            },
            {
                "issuer_id": 2639,
                "Field_of_activity": "Jobs",
                "id": 113,
                "Section": "Communes",
                "Content": "Schnals",
                "foa_section_content_id": 113
            },
            {
                "issuer_id": 2639,
                "Field_of_activity": "Jobs",
                "id": 150,
                "Section": "Professional field",
                "Content": "Marketing, Graphics, PR",
                "foa_section_content_id": 150
            },
            {
                "issuer_id": 2639,
                "Field_of_activity": "Jobs",
                "id": 162,
                "Section": "Branch",
                "Content": "Banks, Finance, Insurance",
                "foa_section_content_id": 162
            },
            {
                "issuer_id": 2639,
                "Field_of_activity": "Jobs",
                "id": 215,
                "Section": "Benefits",
                "Content": "Enrolment programme",
                "foa_section_content_id": 215
            },
            {
                "issuer_id": 2639,
                "Field_of_activity": "Jobs",
                "id": 220,
                "Section": "Benefits",
                "Content": "Childcare",
                "foa_section_content_id": 220
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I need like this output.

```json
{
    "tender_id": 8,
    "job_title": "React developer",
    "enterprise": "Limendo",
    "publishing_date": "2022-11-27T07:43:06.000Z",
    "job_description": "developer for React ",
    "hr-contact": "stefan@limendo.com",
    "adress": "bolzano/italy 5",
    "image": "http://20.216.184.59:3003/public/uploads/company-logos/image-1668363010612.png",
    "job_type": "FULL TIME",
    "employmentType": [
        {
            "id": 198,
            "Employment_type": "Freelancer"
        }
    ],
    "professionalField": [
        {
            "id": 150,
            "Professional_field": "Marketing, Graphics, PR"
        }
    ],
    "benefits": [
        {
            "id": 215,
            "Benefits": "Enrolment programme"
        },
        {
            "id": 219,
            "Benefits": "Canteen"
        },
        {
            "id": 220,
            "Benefits": "Childcare"
        },
        {
            "id": 221,
            "Benefits": "Employee events"
        },
        {
            "id": 222,
            "Benefits": "Employee mobile phone"
        },
        {
            "id": 223,
            "Benefits": "Employee notebook"
        },
        {
            "id": 224,
            "Benefits": "Employee bonuses"
        }
    ],
    "branch": [
        {
            "id": 162,
            "Branch": "Banks, Finance, Insurance"
        }
    ],
    "communes": [],
    "positionLevel": [],
    "skillSets": [],
    "languageSkills": [],
    "skillRepository": [],
    "jobCluster": [],
    "jobClusterDescription": []
}
```